# jQuery Dialog with nested form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog with a nested form inside of it. The form contains an input box and a submit button. When the dialog pops up I want the user to only be able to fill it out, and nothing else on the page. My css for that is done here:

```
.ui-widget-overlay 
{
    height: 1339px !important;
    width: 595px !important;
}
```

This works in allowing the user not to do anything else on the page, but the problem is that the input field is also disabled.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Here is how I make the dialog

```
function dialog(left, top) {

    //Creates a new dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        position: [left, top],
        height: 90,
        width: 200,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span> Enter Info',
    });
}
```

Here is the form I use for the dialog:

```
<!-- Store Location Dialog -->
<div id = "dialog">
    <form id = "info" method = "post" action = "Default.aspx" \> 
        <input type = "text" id = "changeDialogText" name = "changeLocation" /> <!-- THIS IS DISABLED -->
        <input type = "button" id = "changeDialogSubmit" value = ""  onclick = "function()"/> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use [`modal: true`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)? Why fiddle with the CSS?

Comment: I do in my JS. Ill add that code in an edit

Comment: @SsRide how are the fields disabled? Can you clarify?

Comment: I added the code I used to make the dialog. Hopefully that can clears up some questions. Also the button is not disabled, just the input field

Comment: if you're going to use a bunch of double quotes in your string, try wrapping it in single quotes. makes it a lot more readable and less error prone.

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused. Setting the modal to 'true' should disable everything behind the dialog.  What else are you looking to do?

Comment: @SsRide360 - If you are able to, please make a jsFiddle for this so we can see the problem

Comment: I have been trying to make a fiddle, which I will hopefully be able to get out a little later in an edit. What I mean by disabled is that when I try to type any text into the input field nothing happens. This only occurs when `modal: true`

Comment: I have been trying to make a jfiddle, but I really am having troubles getting it to work like my website. I will add the form that I use for the dialog in an edit. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had the `z-index` of my form lower then the `z-index` of the page. This caused issues with the dialog because it was unsure if the input was in the dialog or on page

Comment: I use `z-index:auto` on my forms to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The above does not provide a literal answer that is correct.  `z-Index` auto does not cut it.

```
title: 'Quantity 1',
autoOpen: false,
show: 'slide',
hide: 'explode',
resizable: true,
stack: true,
height: "200",
width: "790",
zIndex: "auto",
modal: true
```